# Disable automatic display of no-data message

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I decided to show "No-data" message in case there is not data.So I enable highchart module(no-data-to-display.js).

This module check if there is data and show or hide label

```
    function handleNoData() {
       var chart = this;
       if (chart.hasData()) {
           chart.hideNoData();
       } else {
           chart.showNoData();
       }
    }
```

And this function bound on event (load,redraw).

```
   /**
     * Add event listener to handle automatic display of no-data message
   */
    chartPrototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {
       H.addEvent(chart, 'load', handleNoData);
       H.addEvent(chart, 'redraw', handleNoData);
    });
```

So my problem is I need show this message **manually(using hideNoData,showNoData functions )**.

So I need somehow disable automatic display of no-data message.Unbind handlers.

Could someone help me?

[Code of no-data-to-display.js](https://stash.development.wvu.edu/projects/CST/repos/code/browse/public/vendor/highcharts/3.0.7/js/modules/no-data-to-display.src.js?at=feature/javascript-quicklinks)

Comment: I think the problem is that you're passing no chart to your function... try with `H.addEvent(chart, 'load', handleNoData(chart));` and `function handleNoData(chart)`

Comment: This is not my function.It's function from highchart module.And I don't want change code in it.

Comment: You can manage this by using `chart.hideNoData()` and `chart.showNoData()` ?

Comment: Yes,ok.But I don't want that it manages automatically on load and redraw events.

Comment: As this module isn't really updated regularly, how about just having your own copy and removing the event listener code?